# The await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync() in HttpClient suddenly stop after many videos downloaded?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, httpclient

After 2-4 downloading of videos data from API using HttpClient suddenly prompt error.
Here's my code:

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetMedia(string id)
{
       var api = $"/api/v1/download/{id}";
       var Uri = $"{MccBaseURL}{api}";

       byte[] responseBody;
       httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("No");

       try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(Uri);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return responseBody;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Print(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
}
```

Then below is the error faced:

[image]

Additional error info:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V97iO.png)
Please help me?

Comment: Are you aware that else `{return null;}` will never run? Because `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` method throws exception when status code is not successful

Comment: my bad. but it's not the issue. do you have any solution?

Comment: Do you have more details on the error? Is that System.Debug.Print because I don't think that is captured in unity's console? I'd use unity's methods like Debug.LogException or Debug.LogError to capture more details.

Comment: could you please specify which .NET version so I can try to reproduce? We need more to try and reproduce this bug. What is the file size?

Comment: Do you create a new `HttpClient` for every message, or is it a singleton?

Comment: @MikeZboray The script is not MonoBehaviour. so i really can't use the unity's method. any ideas how?

Comment: @LuccaFerri I can't tell. In unity its set to .Net 4.x where Unity version is 2019.2.17f1

Comment: @JohnCarloNarval it's difficult to say what's wrong without seeing the detailed error message. My assumption, since you downloading videos, a response not being properly disposed of and you have a memory leak. This could fix the issue: `using(var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(Uri));`. HttpResponseMessage implements IDisposable so wrapping it into using is a sensible move

Comment: @Neil Its singleton.

Comment: @OlegI I've tried this but it's still prompt an error.I'm really frustrated to this kind of error. It not even going to the Debug.WriteLine in VS. I've been tracing this error for a while now. please help.

Comment: Could it be something to do with the fact that you are setting the *default* request headers every time this function is called?  If a different thread/task is just about to write the headers, you go and change them, globally.

Comment: @Neil also done this. still no luck. is there any limit on downloading videos to bytearray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should dispose your `HttpResponseMessage`, as you have in your answer, but not in the original question.

The most likely issue, though, is your use of `DefaultRequestHeaders`.  You should only use this for headers that apply to *every request* that the `HttpClient` instance will send, and then you should *set them only once*, when you create the client, as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders?view=netcore-3.0) implies ("Headers set on this property don't need to be set on request messages again").

While `HttpClient` is essentially thread-safe, the `DefaultRequestHeaders` (and `BaseAddress`) properties are not.  You're changing these values while the client instance is potentially busy using them elsewhere.  It's not clear whether you're using the singleton `HttpClient` elsewhere as well, possibly changing the default headers there too, but if so that would significantly increase the chances of issues arising.

---

Some additional references about the non-thread-safety of these properties:

https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/1085

http://www.michaeltaylorp3.net/httpclient-is-it-really-thread-safe/

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/architecture-center/issues/935

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer which is:

```
public async Task<bool> GetMedia(string saveDir, string id)
        {
            var api = $"/api/v1/download/{id}";
            var Uri = $"{MccBaseURL}{api}";
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(Uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                using (System.IO.Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    string fileToWriteTo = System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName();
                    using (System.IO.FileStream streamToWriteTo = new System.IO.FileStream(saveDir, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It was really memory something problem which continuously using same HttpClient over and over again. So I created a new instance. I'm a super noob! Sorry!

Comment: This is exactly how not to use `HttpClient`. It is intended to be a singleton that is used across threads; see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8) and especially the text there: "Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads".

Comment: Yes exactly. I've used that "Instantiate once" but that produces that error. I dunno why but I don't know how anymore. So please provide sample or complete solution for me to understand. Thanks!

Comment: Bit too long for a comment, but see the answer I just added.